# List Azure VM custom extensions with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-extension

I need to install a custom execution script to Azure VM through terraform. The challenge though is we can only have one (custom)extension. So I need to delete any existing extensions before I add a new one.
To delete an extension, I should know the name of the extension. Below is the code to delete it (if I know the name) and this works fine. But this approach fails, if the custom extension does not exist.
Question is, how do I query and find if the extension exists? One approach is to use “null_resource”. I’d like to keep that as my last choice. Wondering if there are any other ways to list them, especially the custom one's?

```
resource "azapi_resource_action" "delete_vm_custom_extension" {
  provider             = azapi
  for_each = local.vm_extensions
  type        = Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2023-03-01
  resource_id = "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_client_config.this.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${var.data_factory.resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/${each.value.vm}/extensions/${each.value.custom_extension}"
  method      = "DELETE"
  response_export_values = ["*"]
}
```

It'd be nice if I can achieve the same with azapi methods

Comment: You use azapi_resource_action to remove an extension by its name. But Terraform cannot query Azure resources and list their extensions before deleting them. This makes it hard to manage resources dynamically based on their current state in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to install a custom execution script to Azure VM through terraform,The challenge though is we can only have one (custom)extension. So I need to delete any existing extensions before I add a new one. To delete an extension.

As there is no direct way to check the existing extensions before creating the new one on `Azure VM` with conditions such as wanting to delete any extensions found and install a new one if not found, all these conditions are not possible via `Terraform` without using a null resource.

**PowerShell script:**

The `PowerShell` script will first list all extensions. If extensions are found, it will iterate through them, delete each extension one by one using `Remove-AzVMExtension`, and install a new extension on the **Azure VM**.

**script.ps1**

```
    # Specify VM details
    $resourceGroupName = "testvk-rg"
    $vmName = "testvmvkserver"
    $extenname = "IaaSAntimalware"
    
    # Get the VM
    $vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName
    
    # Delete all extensions
    if ($vm.Extensions.Count -gt 0) {
        Write-Output "Deleting extensions on VM '$vmName':"
        $vm.Extensions | ForEach-Object {
            $extensionName = $_.Name
            Write-Output "Deleting extension: $extensionName"
            Remove-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -VMName $vmName -Name $extensionName -Force
        }
    } else {
        Write-Output "No extensions found on VM '$vmName'."
    }
    Write-Output "Installing a new extension on VM '$vmName':"
    
    $SettingsString = "{ ""AntimalwareEnabled"": true }"
    Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location "East US" -VMName $vmName -Name $extenname  -Publisher "Microsoft.Azure.Security" -Type "IaaSAntimalware" -TypeHandlerVersion "1.3" -SettingString $SettingsString
    Write-Output "Installed extension named: '$extenname' on VM '$vmName'"
```

**Terraform code:**

> Note: Make sure to place both the `script.ps1` and the Terraform file in the **same directory**.

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
          features {}
        }
        resource "null_resource" "execute_powershell" {
          provisioner "local-exec" {
            command = <<-EOT
              powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ${path.module}/script.ps1
            EOT
          }
        }
```

**terraform apply**

[image]

**Portal result**

[image]